# Connecting a client application to a Nodejs chaincode running on local fabric network in Vscode's blockchain platform extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

I am running a local Fabric network in the VScode's IBM blockchain platform extension. I have installed and instantiated my chaincode in the local fabric and I can connect to the environment through the Fabric's Gateway panel and execute chaincode invoke and query functions using the extension.

I know I can export the local's fabric gateway connection profile and the wallet.

My question is - if I a have a client application running Fabric Node SDK, can I connect my locally running client application to this local network using this connection profile?

It seems that this connectionProfile is missing some crucial information, such as tlsCACerts path..

Can somewhere instruct me on if/how it is possible to connect a client application to this local fabric environment running my chaincode?

Answer (score 0):

Yup! If you have a connection profile and a wallet (with an identity), you have all the details required to connect to the chaincode and submit transactions.

Take a look at the samples for some example applications which do this - https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples